# Force WSO2 to login with google every time

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, wso2, google-oauth, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a Rails application and I have configured WSO2is with Oauth 2.0 with it to login with Google. It works fine. But there is an issue with it. Example suppose I log in with one of my Google accounts and then log out of my application. and then I try to login with another Google accounts, here WSO2 does not prompt me with a google login screen again. My question is how to force WSO2 to prompt login every time.

Comment: May we assume you are using WSO2 Identity Server with OAuth2? Which version?

Comment: @gusto2 I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Google federated authenticator[2] does not support logout functionality hence logout request will not be delivered to Google IDP.

If you want to support logout functionality in given authenticator need to override initiateLogoutRequest() method in the authenticator itself. If you have a look Google federated authenticator[2] there is no implementation of initiateLogoutRequest(). But if you have a look SAML federated authenticator[1] there is a implementation for initiateLogoutRequest() where it does support federated logout.

Since initiateLogoutRequest() is not overriden in Google federated authenticator[2] AbstractApplicationAuthenticator --> initiateLogoutRequest() will be invoked which does nothing [3][4].

If you really need to implement federated logout for Google authenticator, extend Google federated authenticator[2]  and implement initiateLogoutRequest() as per Google IDP requirement.

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-samlsso/blob/v5.1.12/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/samlsso/SAMLSSOAuthenticator.java#L361

[2] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-google/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.google/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/google/GoogleOAuth2Authenticator.java

[3] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/v5.12.148/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/framework/AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java#L118

[4] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/v5.12.148/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/framework/AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java#L196